# How to remove all items in a list of lists that are not unique?

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates

I'm trying to calculate all unique subgroups of the multiplicative group Z*_7. You can find everything on groups here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group .

I've tried a lot already. Sets don't really help since they are only removing all duplicated lists but  keep one item of the initially not unique lists. I've read quite a few posts here on stackoverflow but none of them really help.

So all possible subgroups of 7 are:

> [[1], [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], [1, 7, 13], [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], [1, 7, 13], [1, 17]]

My desired result however should look like this:

> [[1], [1, 17]]

Since [1, 7, 13] and [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17] are not unique lists in this subgroup I want to have them removed entirely.

Comment: Use a counter (convert the lists to tuples) and select only those with value = 1. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can achieve it with the following:

```
data = [[1], [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], [1, 7, 13], [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], [1, 7, 13], [1, 17]]

print([x for x in data if data.count(x) ==1])
```

Output:

> [[1], [1, 17]]